# How to update a value with signals in Django

Tags: python, django, signals

Im trying to update an attribute with a signal with post_save, but im getting an ExceptionType: TypeError "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Pedido'", and I dont know what is this error.

This is my signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Venta)
def update_thread(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']

    obj = Pedido.objects.get(pk=instance.pedido)
    obj.estado = "Finalizado"
    ob.save()
```

Also check this:
[image: error]

What could be the error?

**Edit:**
Those are my two models im using here:

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    fecha = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, null=True, blank=True)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Pendiente')
    cliente = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Agregue Cliente')
    observacion = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, default='Ninguna')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('control:pedido-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Venta(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, null=True, blank=True)
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido, db_column='pedido_id', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    total = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=1)
    cliente = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nit = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('control:venta-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: It seems like `instance.pedido` is not an integer or foreign key but rather just a string. Can you post your `Venta` model code?

Comment: I edited with the code @azundo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're searching the db by `pk` you need an id, not the actual instance, so to fix your error you could do:

```
obj = Pedido.objects.get(pk=instance.pedido.pk)
```

However that's kind of circular - since you have a `ForeignKey` you should be able to access the related object directly, no need to do the db lookup.

```
obj = instance.pedido
obj.estado = "Finalizado"
obj.save()  # note there is a typo in your original code here - was ob.save()
```